# Add a Leading Zero with a number field

Tags: templating

I have a number field used for episode numbers and I would like to automatically add a leading zero when the number is less than 10. I have this working with a conditional but it seems inefficient. Is there a twig filter that I don't know about that does this?

```
{% if entry.episodeNumber < "10" %}
    {% set episodeNumber = '0' ~ entry.episodeNumber %}
{% else %}
    {% set episodeNumber = entry.episodeNumber %}
{% endif %}
```

The above works but seems overly long to accomplish what should be a simple task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There aren't any filters built in to Craft (or Twig) that does this, but your `{% if %}` conditional could be trimmed down to a single-line *ternary operation*:

```
{% set episodeNumber = (entry.episodeNumber < 10 ? '0') ~ entry.episodeNumber %}
```

or even

```
<span>{{ (entry.episodeNumber < 10 ? '0') ~ entry.episodeNumber }}</span>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use PHP's sprintf function via [the format filter in Twig].[1](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format.html)

So to add a leading zero to single digit numbers:

`{{ "%02d"|format('4') }}`

Which would return `04`

---

Or in your case `{{ "%02d"|format(entry.episodeNumber) }}`